# Using a IF Statement within a TSQL UPDATE

Tags: t-sql

I want to update two columns in a table.  The value of the second column is dependant upon the first;  If the first is Null the second's value is 'false', otherwise it is 'true'.
Can I do this within TSQL or do I need to work out the values separately in my code before hand and change the SQL to suit.  I was looking for something like:

```
DECLARE @NewColumnValue as nvarchar(10);
SELECT @NewColumnValue = ColumnY From TableY
UPDATE TableX  
SET Column1 = @NewColumnValue,
Column2 = (IF (@NewColumnValue IS NULL) THEN 'False' ELSE 'True');
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are looking for the [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression:

```
Column2 = CASE WHEN @NewColumnValue IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END
```